# zsh extended globbing not working as expected

Tags: zsh

I have `extendedglob` enabled in `zsh`, but extended globbing does not seem to work:

```
$ print -l /etc/*.@(cfg|conf)
zsh: no matches found: /etc/*.@(cfg|conf)

$ print -l /etc/*.(conf)
zsh: number expected
```

how can I use regular expressions to list files in /etc which end either in `.conf` or in `.cfg` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrong syntax. The `@(...)` construct is not related to EXTENDED GLOB, but to KSH_GLOB.

```
setopt extendedglob
print -l /etc/*.(cfg|conf)
```

As a side note, you can even then not use regular expressions to generate file lists. Regular expressions can only be used to match strings.